Attach policy to existing ecr using Serverless
Is there a way to attach the lifecycle policy to the existing ecr repo using serverless?
So serverless supports the docker deployment now, with below sample config.
 ecr: {
      images: {
        appImage: {
          path: ".",
        },
      },
    },


This defines the ECR but doesnt give a way to define lifecycle policy for this ECR. And multiple deployments can create memory issues here.
So I am trying to attach a lifecycle policy to this ecr so that some cleanup can be done.
Thanks for the help.

I'm not really sure what do you want to achieve and why. If you're asking - is there a way - usually it means there is. 
Under "serverless" do oyu mean lambda? Just call the PutLifecyclePolicy operation, the lambda needs to have the permission to do so. Where is the problem? What are you struggling with exacly?

Hi @gusto2 Updated the question,Please suggest
